# Would a Repo owner be notified if someone put a new comment on a CLOSED issue in github?

Tags: github, github-issues

It is a simple question I could not find an answer for by googling and looking at the [github documents](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-issues).

Would a Repo owner be notified if someone put a new comment on a closed issue in github?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If a comment is added to a ***closed*** issue, notifications ***are*** sent to the **`REPO OWNER`** *assuming* the owner is ***`watching`*** that repo.

---

***Note:*** There's a subtle but important clarification to notice here: If you create a repo in your **personal** account, GitHub automatically sets you as a `watcher` of your repo. Eg. You'll be notified of code pushes, when issues are created/closed, etc. Technically speaking (and being a little pedantic), but being a `"repo owner"` as the SO question asks, isn't the trigger of notifications. (Ie. You could be a repo owner but just "un-watch" the repo; you'd then miss all subsequent notifications, obviously.) It's being a `repo watcher` that is important.

With `personal` accounts, you are automatically set as a `watcher` on any repo you create.

With `organization` accounts, ***you are not***. (Eg. If you create a repo in an `organization` account, GitHub will not automatically set you as a `watcher` of that repo.) In an `organization` account, after you create a repo, if you care about its notifications (like issue notifications), you will need to watch it manually. Eg. Click `Watch` in the upper-right corner:

[image]

---

**Screenshots:**

[image]

To test, I created an issue, closed it, and then commented against the closed issue (without reopening it; ie. I clicked on the the green "Comment" button). Shortly afterwards, I received this email notification in my inbox:

[image]

**Note:** I am the repo owner and am watching it. Additionally though, when notifications were sent, they were sent to:

- All members subscribed to the repo
- Anyone who's commented on the issue
- The issue's original author
- The person who closed the issue

Whether the issue was opened or closed did not affect the usual notification behavior.

---

**Edit (7/11/21)**: I spent an additional hour this afternoon testing how notifications work on closed issues in GitHub and wanted to just add these screenshots for completeness:

- On a **closed** issue, if you ever ***commented*** before on the issue, and another comment is made to the closed issue, you will *still* receive a notification:

[image]

- On a **closed** issue, if you were the person who ***closed the issue***, and another comment is made to the closed issue, you will *still* receive a notification:

[image]

- On a **closed** issue, if you ever ***manually subscribed to the thread***, and another comment is made to the closed issue, you will *still* receive a notification:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But is there any way to check if these specifications are still the same as of 2023?

Comment: I confirmed that they're notified at least as of May 2023.